# Open WebView links in Safari

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

When Running the app it first loads, then loads the web page in safari. How would I make the page load in the `UIWebView` and have the external links in the `webView` open in safari?

Here is some of the Code of The webviewcontroller.m -

```
#import "WebViewController.h"


@implementation WebViewController

@synthesize webView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

/*
 If you need to do additional setup after loading the view, override viewDidLoad. */
- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSString *urlAddress = @"url link goes here";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

@end

Answer (score 0):

The reason the first page is loading in Safari instead of your `UIWebView` in your app is this line of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Remove this line from your `viewDidLoad` method.

In order to make links inside your `webView` load in the Safari app, first set your view controller as the delegate for the webView with `webView.delegate = self;` inside the `viewDidLoad` method.

Then add the following code to your `viewController`:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This method will get called every time the `webView` is about to start loading a request. What it does is check if the request was initiated by a click by the user. In case it was, it opens Safari and loads the request there. Any other requests that were not initiated by a click are loaded within your application, such as the request for your start page.